# Proof of convergence for BV functions

Tags: functional-analysis

I am working on approximation of BV functions. I end up with this issue: I would like to prove that $f: \mathcal{K}\subset \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $\mathcal{K}$ is a compact set, converges to $f(u_n(\cdot))$ where $u_n(\cdot)$ belongs to a ball of $\mathbb{R}^n$ centered at $x$ and with a radius $\delta$ that goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

In 1D (i.e. when $n=1$), it is not that difficult: you say that $x-\delta \leq u_n(x)\leq x+\delta$ and use the fact that any BV function can be written as the difference between two increasing functions, let us say that $f=f_1-f_2$ where, $f_i$ is an increasing function. You therefore have

$f_i(x-\delta)\leq f_i(u_n(x))\leq f_i(x+\delta)$

Hence, you have $|f_i(u_n(x))-f_i(x)|\leq |f_i(x+\delta)-f_i(x)|$ and then you integrate this inequality and obtain

$\int_{\mathcal{K}} |f_i(u_n(x))-f_i(x)| dx\leq \delta \frac{1}{\delta}\int_{\mathcal{K}}|f_i(x+\delta)-f_i(x)| dx$.

Using the fact that the total variation norm is given by

$\limsup_{\delta\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\delta}\int_{\mathcal{K}}|f_i(x+\delta)-f_i(x)| dx$

then you have the convergence. Note that I might have wrong with this proof.

My question is therefore the following : does this proof work also with the multiD case (i.e., when $n\geq 2$) ?